# Amazon S3 and CloudFront - compressed files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

concerning Amazon's documentation it is possible to serve compressed files via CloudFront/S3, if I upload a compressed and an uncompressed version of the same file. Both files need to have the same content type, the compressed additionally needs to have Content-Encoding set to "gzip".

So now I have two files on S3:

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kiga-client/gzip/client/config.js

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kiga-client/gzip/client/config.js.gz

On my website I create a link to CloudFront which links to the config.js on

https://d1v5g5yve3hx29.cloudfront.net/gzip/client/config.js

I would now expect that I get automatically a compressed file when the client sends Accept-Encoding "gzip" via:

```
curl -I -H  'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' https://d1v5g5yve3hx29.cloudfront.net/gzip/client/config.js
```

Unfortunately I get the raw file returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Content-Length: 3509
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 11:12:43 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Last-Modified: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 10:50:15 GMT
ETag: "c310121403754f4faab782504912c15c"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Age: 2405
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 8a256bddd45845f932a0a374e95fa057.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 4HRqstvYGYD1A-vfvltNrXGffg0D5XbFjSpoWReI5UNYf-2jQfE8jQ==
```

The response header Content-Encoding: gzip should be set but is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serve compressed files you need to actually request compressed file's URL from CloudFront. See pt. 5 here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#CompressedS3

Answer (score 0):

To be precise one actually has to compress the files manually and then upload them to S3 with the appropriate metadata.

Further more one must keep the original filename, although the file is compressed.

So given a file image.jpg which gets compress to image.jpg.gz one has to upload image.jpg.gz and rename it to image.jpg